# What is the best way to arrange trapezoidable bricks to form a giant circle?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

I have some bricks that form a trapezoid shape. They have the following dimensions:

a = 4.25 in

b = 9.05 in

c = 2.375 in

d = 9.05 in

[image]

[image]

I want to arrange these such that they form a giant lawn circle, with a radius of 255 inches (circumference of 1602 inches), without any gaps between them.

- Gaps are to be avoided as much as possible.
- The bricks are to be set on top of a perfectly circular wall that is already constructed. It has a 255-inch radius.
- The bricks can overlap the 255-inch circle, in fact that is desired as it would look poor if they are perfectly flush, but they can't overlap more than 1".
- They can be arranged so either side $\overline{a}$ or $\overline{c}$ are pointing outwards.

The bricks sit on a wall like this, except the wall forms a perfect circle:

[image]

If I simply arrange them within the circle, with side $\overline{a}$ along the circumference, it has many large gaps between the bricks, which is not good:

[image]

If I arrange them in an alternating pattern, some with side $\overline{a}$ along the circumference, while others with $\overline{c}$ along the circumference, I can reduce the gaps, but there are still many large gaps visible:

[image]

Unfortunately, with this pattern, if no gaps are given, the bricks just form a straight line and do not match the curve of the circle. Note that the goal is a nice fit around the circumference, without any gaps:

[image]

If I create some pattern, such that it alternates between sides $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{c}$ being placed outwards, before having two $\overline{a}$'s outwards in a row, this creates a giant regular polygon. This is an ideal solution, as no gaps are present between bricks. A small extra overlap outside the circle is also welcome athletically.

[image]

The best solution I can come up with it to create a giant tetracontakaitrigon (43-sided regular polygon) using 43 sets of six $\overline{a}$-out-facing and five $\overline{c}$-out-facing blocks. Each set is rotated by 8 degrees, leaving a gap of ~3 degrees of gap between the sets. I believe I calculated the degrees right, as in there will be an empty gap between sets, and it doesn't require something impossible, like bricks magically overlapping.

- Each set would measure 37.375 inches, so 43 sets would create a circumference of 1607.125 inches.
- This slightly larger circumference would mean the bricks need to overlap the circumference by .39 inches at the center of each set of bricks.
- The solution requires 473 bricks.

[image]

Did I make any mistakes in my calculations?

Is there a better solution that reduces the 3-degree gaps between bricks?

Comment: By my reckoning, if you extend the sides of the trapezoid (whether one brick or 2n+1 alternating bricks) you get an angle of 11.89°; so your polygon should have 30 sides, leaving 3.24° *total* error to be divided among all the bricks.  How did you get 43?

Comment: Is the 255ʺ circle to be approximated by the inner or outer edge of the ring of bricks?

Comment: @AntonSherwood The outer edge of the ring of bricks should be overlapping 255ʺ, preferably by about 1/2" to 1".

Comment: @AntonSherwood By my calculations, 30 sides would be ideal, because there would be nearly 0 space between bricks, because 30 sides creates an 11 degree angle to match the 11 degree angle on these bricks...but I couldn't figure a pattern that fit...that if 8 bricks one way, 9 the other way as a set, that leaves a giant 18 inch overlap...7 bricks in, 8 bricks out creates a circle 13 inches too small...unless I'm just not understanding how to solve it right.

Comment: @AntonSherwood If we assume a 1" overlap over the bricks, the circumference becomes 1608.5 inches. Divide that by 30, leaves 53.6" for each of the 30 sides. 30 sides comprising 7 outward/8 inward facing bricks measures 50.5 inches, so abou3 3 inches short, while 8 outward/9 inward facing bricks measures 57.25 inches, meaning each side is far too wide.

Comment: Use a mix of group sizes. 25 groups of 15 blocks and 6 groups of 17 blocks, with the larger groups spaced as evenly as possible, should work out quite well.

Comment: My best result uses 478 bricks: 16 sets of 15 and 14 sets of 17, resulting in a slight deviation from circularity, which will probably be smaller than the inevitable inaccuracy of the bricks.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Comment:

The angle of brick $2\alpha$ is:

$sin(\alpha)=\frac{4.25-2.375}{2\times9,05}=0.1000..$

$\alpha≈ 5.75^o $ ⇒ $2\alpha=11.5^o$

The radius of the garden is $255"$ we have:

$d=255 sin (11.5) ≈ 50.84" $

Now if you make a set of 5 bricks, you get a trapezoid ( as shown in figure) we have:

Short side of trapezoid : $2\times4.25+3\times2.375=7.125$

Long side of trapezoid: $3\times 4.25+2\times 2.375=17.5$

Now a set out of three of these sets has outer side as:

$2\times 17.5+15.625=50.625 $

This almost equal to $d=50.84$

That means you have to make sets of 5 bricks; total number of brick is:

$\frac{360}{11.5}\times 15=469.5 ≈470$

Comment: $\sin(\alpha)=\frac{4.25-2.375}{2\times9.05}\approx 0.10359\implies\alpha\approx 5.946^o\implies 2\alpha\approx 11.892^o$

Comment: You are right, but we are trying for a rough estimation for bricks and garden not a Physical experiment which requires high accuracy.